# JavaScript / jQuery - Recognize Type of Form Input (i.e. radio button, text input, dropdown)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get my JS to recognize the type of form input that is visible on the page. I'm doing a quiz, and when you hit the "next" button, it will show the next question, as long as the previous question was answered. If it was not, it should show an alert. I'm trying to get JS to recognize the type of input the question has so that it can get see if no radio button was checked, if the question was a radio button question. But so far, it's recognizing all questions as text AND radio questions. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I've been working on this for hours.

Here is the JS Fiddle: http://bitly.com/1qy5TiX

Here is the code:

```
 $("button").click(function() {
 if ($("input:visible [type=text]") || $("select") ) {
    console.log("this is text or select");
 }
 if ($("input:visible :radio")) {
    console.log("this is radio");
 }
 showNext();
 }); // end button click function
```

Comment: `$('select').length` will be non-zero even if the `<select>` is hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote you a very basic validation function since you only have one question visible at a time. You may want to look into validation libraries as well but this should get you going on the right track:

```
function isValid() {
    var $form = $('form:visible'),
        $input = $form.find('input'),
        $select = $form.find('select');

    var type = $input.length ? 'input' : ($select.length ? 'select' : 'error');

    if (type == 'error') {
        alert('invalid input type found');
        return false;
    }

    if ($form.find('input[type="radio"]').length) {
        return $form.find('input[type="radio"]:checked').length;    
    }

    var inputVal = $form.find(type).val();

    return inputVal !== null && inputVal.length;
}
```

You can check if the form is valid like so:

```
$("button").click(function () {
    console.log('form is valid: ' + isValid());
    if (!isValid()) {
        alert("Please enter a response.");
    } else {
        ...
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tomanow/mpjg2vbk/17/)

Also, you will probably want to replace `'form:visible'` with something more concrete.

Comment: Thank you. To help me understand the code - why do you use dollar signs in your variables? (i.e. var $form = ...)

Comment: Oh, it just lets me know that the variable is a jQuery object =P . You can of course omit the dollar sign from the variable.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but it doesn't give an alert if I don't enter an answer for question 5. It's the second radio button question. I thought maybe .find only found the first match but looking at the jquery documentation, it doesn't look like that's the reason why.

Comment: When question 5 is not answered, it is recording the answer as "yes." It's not checked but for some reason, jquery thinks it is. Even if I select "no", it records the answer as yes in the console log.

Comment: It is probably because I didn't prepend the form find selection. I will update

Comment: Updated, simply add `$form.find` like so: `return $form.find('input[type="radio"]:checked').length;`

Comment: Thank you. I have a couple of questions, if you don't mind. :) What does the return false do after the error alert? Also, in this statement: return inputVal !== null && inputVal.length;, it's saying return the value if an answer was given, correct? Why does it not need an if statement; how does it know that it means return it as long as the condition is true?

Comment: I just put in a check to make sure the form has either an `input` or `select` visible. That can be omitted of course.